# Correct way to "bubble up" errors from a model, to a view, to a template in Python Flask framework

Tags: python, error-handling, flask

What's the proper way to catch errors in my class, and have error messages "bubble up" from the class, to the view, and finally be display on the template?

The problem I have now, is I end up catching the same errors twice, in both my models and view controllers. This doesn't feel right.

Here's an example:

model/user.py

```
class User(object):
   errors = []

  def __init__(self, string=None):
    """ Initialize the user object
    """

    #See if the input string is an e-mail address
    try:
      string_is_email = string.index('@')
    except ValueError:
      self.errors.append('Invalid e-mail address')
      raise ValueError
```

view/login.py

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']

    #Catch invalid e-mails
    try:
      u = User(email)
    except ValueError:
      errors = u.errors

  #In case the user hasn't POSTED
  try:
    errors = u.errors
  except:
    errors = None

  return render_template('login.html', error=errors)
```

templates/login.html

```
    {% if error %}
    <div class="error">
      <ul>
        {% for message in error %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I dont think you need the try/except in the `models/user.py` ... since errors will automagically bubble up if not caught

Comment: I'm really doing that to set an error message. If I don't have that try/except in there, I'd have to put the message in the view. But then if I use the class in another view, I'd have to duplicate the code

Answer (score 4):

Instead of that errors hack, you can directly send the message to the template with [flash](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/). Furthermore, I would modify it a bit:

```
class User(object):
  def __init__(self, string):
    """ Initialize the user object
    """

    #See if the input string is an e-mail address
    try:
      string_is_email = string.index('@')
    except ValueError:
      raise ValueError('Invalid e-mail address')

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
  if request.method == 'POST':

    email = request.form['email']
    password = request.form['password']

    #Catch invalid e-mails
    try:
      u = User(email)
    except ValueError, e:
      flash(e.message)
```

On how to use `flash`, have a look into the documentation: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/flashing/.

Comment: So it's necessary to catch the same error in both places (in the class, and in the controller?)

Comment: No, but it makes the most sense and this code allows you to throw different `ValueError`s with different messages and you have to catch them just once.